MDX interprets text inside {} braces as a JS expression instead of Latex
$$
10^{-Q/10}
$$

This will give the following error: Q is not defined. It happens with inline and display math, Katex and Mathjax.
How can I escape the braces? Or is there an alternative syntax that I can use?

The markdown that you supplied here is close enough to what is provided in the MDX math docs that the syntax is unlikely to be the problem. It seems that more information is needed. Perhaps a minimal working example that includes details for how you invoke the katex/mathjax plugins will help.
